# How to disable ClearType from all programs on Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, cleartype

I want to disable ClearType fonts rendering from all programs, including Firefox and any other random program I might be using that uses this feature.

This does not help me (in fact its already set to standard for me):

[image]

OS: Windows XP SP3

Comment: Have you tried to unset the checkbox right above the combo on the screenshot, "use the following method to smooth edges of screen fonts"?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs, but i want to have smooth fonts sometimes. Just that the ClearType is annoying to my eyes (i can see the blues and yellows at the edges easily, and im not using bad LCD nor CRT as some people have told me before). edit: tried it but didnt do anything.

Comment: This *should* work. If it doesn't - this must be a bug probably. Do you have any other tweak tools installed perhaps?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs, i dont have any tools installed, almost fresh windows xp install. the problem is that some programs decide whether or not use ClearType by themselves, without giving windows XP any chance to intervene.

Answer (score 1):

Have you attempted to [Tune the ClearType](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/step1.aspx) system-wide?

Firefox attempts to handle it's own font smoothing, so perhaps check out the FF ["Anti-Aliasing Tuner" plug-in](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/anti-aliasing-tuner/?src=api), and/or type turning off Hardware Acceleration in FF, so that it stops trying to smooth the fonts. :)

Comment: Firefox isnt the only program that does this. there are many many more programs which settings i would have to change one at a time (but in 99.99% cases that setting is not changeable). So i thought, maybe there is a hack in Windows XP that would completely destroy the ClearType engine and replace it with basic antialiasing, so no program could even use it anymore if they wanted, unless, of course, they would build their own engine... which they probably do... unfortunately.

Comment: The "Anti-Aliasing Tuner" plug-in doesn't support XP.